# Different values for datetime, date and time fields from timestamp in MySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime, unix-timestamp

I am trying to convert a `TIMESTAMP` to the `DATETIME`, `DATE` and `TIME` MySQL types using the `FROM_UNIXTIME` field. I noticed that the values for `TIME` and `DATETIME` fields have different time information on them.

Instead of the insert statement to the table, I am replacing it with a simple select statement that prints the values:

```
select FROM_UNIXTIME('1468561341') as timestamp_datetime,FROM_UNIXTIME('1468561341','%d/%m/%y') as timestamp_date, FROM_UNIXTIME('1468561341','%h:%m:%s %p') as timestamp_time
```

The results look like this:

- timestamp_datetime: `2016-07-15 05:42:21.000000`
- timestamp_date `15/07/16`
- timestamp_time `05:07:21 AM`

How can I get consistent time value in both these columns?

Comment: What do you mean about *consistent time value*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is with letter m

it should be i

```
mysql> select FROM_UNIXTIME(1468561341) as timestamp_datetime,FROM_UNIXTIME(1468561341,'%d/%m/%y') as timestamp_date, FROM_UNIXTIME(1468561341,'%h:%i:%s %p') as timestamp_time;
+---------------------+----------------+----------------+
| timestamp_datetime  | timestamp_date | timestamp_time |
+---------------------+----------------+----------------+
| 2016-07-15 05:42:21 | 15/07/16       | 05:42:21 AM    |
+---------------------+----------------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.05 sec)
```

Comment: %m means month not minute to get minute please use i

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that in your FROM_UNIXTIME you are essentially telling it to do

```
hours-months-seconds -AM/PM
```

But you want

```
hours-minutes-seconds -AM/PM
```

So change it to

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(1468561341,'%h:%i:%s %p')
```

instead.

Reference guide for all the time parameters and usage of time functions in MySQL here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html